# Android UI home screen design

Tags: android-listview, android

I am up to create a section on my Android Home screen similar to this one,

[image: Icons]

but cannot really figuring out where to start. I mean is this a ListView I should go with? or are these simple images that are placed as different objects surrounded by straight lines? In either case, how to put these things together, is a question that I am wondering..

Comment: You can use gridview layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use:

- a `GridLayout` (for API < 14, there is a [support library available somewhere on GitHub](https://github.com/dlew/android-gridlayout))
- a vertical `LinearLayout` containing two horizontal `LinearLayout`s
- a single `RelativeLayout`

For the buttons, use `TextView` or `Button` with a top drawable.

Please note that the dashboard pattern is now discouraged ([link 1](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html), [link 2](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2012/09/is-the-dashboard-pattern-dead-2/)) (you should present useful information to the user on first screen such as there latest trips, friend's news, ...).

Instead of that, you could put your buttons in a sliding menu ([jfeinstein](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) has a nice implementation on github which can be integrated within an hour)